# is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous on my .exe apps

Tags: vb.net, security-warning

I have a vb.net app and when i download it on any browser from any computer from any place i see this warning:
`is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous`
I don't find nothing anywhere. I tried to sign it, yo use Windows Certification Kit, and a lot of things, but still nothing. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If you signed it then you shouldn't get this error provided it simply wasn't a self-signed certificate

Comment: @Ramhound This is not exactly correct. Using a certificate signed by a trusted CA will accumulate SmartScreen reputation for the certificate (as opposed to just one particular binary) so the downloads of _any_ of your applications will boost the reputation of _all_ of them. The warning will still appear though (however the UAC _will_ look less scary though.

Comment: I suppose I failed to mention there are other requirements not to get the notification but they are also published by Microsoft, so I didn't think, I needed to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231581/program-download-ie-chrome-is-not-commonly-downloaded-and-could-be-dangerou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are seeing is triggered by SmartScreen. On a pre Windows 8 machine, you will only see this if you use IE. On Windows 8, SmartScreen is enabled on the OS level. SmartScreen displays this warning based on your applications reputation score.

If you want to download this yourself, you should be able to fine the "Run anyway" option.

If you are concerned about what other people will see when they download your software, there are no easy shortcuts. You **can:**

1. Sign your application with a certificate issued by a CA trusted by Windows (this will not make the warning go away, but makes it easier to accumulate app reputation, as it will give you the combined reputation of *all* applications you sign with the same certificate).
2. Make sure your application is not being detected as malware by AV software (try using [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)).
3. Get your app certified by Microsoft. Running the Certification Kit is not enough. You must submit your results to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/jj134964.aspx).

Over time, as people download your app, its reputation will rise, and eventually it will no longer trigger SmartScreen warnings.